# multiple checkboxes at least 1 required in html 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want as HTML error message rather than an alert message, I've found few solutions but none are not working as hoped

```js
$('form').on('click', '.required_group', function() {
  $('input.required_group').prop('required', $('input.required_group:checked').length === 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="whatever" value="1" required class="required_group" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="whatever" value="2" required class="required_group" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="whatever" value="3" required class="required_group" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="whatever" value="4" required class="required_group" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: The code you've shown works for me in Chrome; I see the 'required' notification when I click the button with no checkboxes selected. Can you be clearer what the issue is.

Comment: Firefox 60.0.2 works as well [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/UwwUSpQ.png)

Comment: thankx its working proper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('form').on('click', '.required_group', function() {
var flag=false;
 $('.required_group').each(function(e){
    if (this.checked) {
             flag=true;
     }
  });
if(!flag){
       // Do your code for Error Message
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method with a custom error message.

It looks at everything with the class `required_group` and counts every instance where it is checked. If the number is 0 it sets a custom message and triggers it, however, if there is one or more it will reset the message and trigger a submit.

```js
function validateGrp() {
  let things = document.querySelectorAll('.required_group')
  let checked = 0;
  for (let thing of things) {
    thing.checked && checked++
  }
  if (checked) {
    things[things.length - 1].setCustomValidity("");
    document.getElementById('checkGroup').submit();
  } else {
    things[things.length - 1].setCustomValidity("You must check at least one checkbox");
    things[things.length - 1].reportValidity();
  }
}

document.querySelector('[name=submit]').addEventListener('click', () => {
  validateGrp()
});
```

```html
<form id="checkGroup">
  <input type="checkbox" name="whatever" value="1" class="required_group" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="whatever" value="2" class="required_group" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="whatever" value="3" class="required_group" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="whatever" value="4" class="required_group" />
  <button name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```